# Почему на PHP код не работает как на Javascript?

Tags: php

Есть Javacript и работает идеально:

```
if (!navigator.cookieEnabled || !window.caches) {
  document.cookie = "referrer=" + document.referrer;
  window.history.back();
}
```

Но на PHP возвращает на домен (например возвращает yandex.ru, а заходил с yandex.ru/kupti-slona), а мне надо на предыдущую страницу.

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['referrer']) && (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL']) || $_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL'] !== 'max-age=0')) {
    setcookie('referrer', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], time() + 3600, '/');
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Глобальная $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] уже давно почти не поддерживается и при 90% случаев данная переменная будет пуста.